# Prevent Firefox from opening a new tab when it starts

Tags: firefox

I have some pinned tabs in my Firefox (IM web clients) and everytime when I start Firefox a new panel is created and takes focus.

I want to see my first (or what was last active) pinned panel when FF starts. How to do it?

[image]

- `General > Startup` is set to `Restore previous session`
- I looked on [about:config](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox#w_opening-aboutconfig), but didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: If you set Firefox to restore previous session on startup and a new window (same size as the main window, by the way?) opens and steals focus, it means that one of the websites you want restored on startup is forcing it to, probably an login window in one of the IM web clients you use, or a warning of some sort. Try to restart Firefox with only one of those clients open, check if the extra-window appears, and if not, do it again with another client, until you find which one is causing the issue. There may be some setting with that client that can prevent that, but you have to know which one.

Comment: I added image with actual behavior. It is not a new window. It's a new panel with FF start page, like as when + right from panels is clicked.

Comment: One thing you can try: open all the pages you want restored on startup, then go to your Firefox options / preferences in the burger menu, and on Home / Home, choose "Use current page(s)", without changing anything else. If that fails, go to General and uncheck "Restore previous session". You may have added an extra pipe somewhere.

Comment: @Didier Thanks for reply. It's work (kinda). When I set to open these addresses in `Homepage and new windows`, Firefox starts and opens these pages. But it opens them in new tabs - so there are duplicated - one instance in a pinned tab and second in a new tab. :-/

Comment: You might have to reset your user preferences, then. Close Firefox, wait a few seconds, then go to your user profile AppData (hidden) folder, then in both Roaming and Local, locate the Mozilla Firefox Profile folder (the one pertaining to your working copy of Firefox; if there are several, choose the one that was last modified today), and cut-paste the prefs.js files, one onto your Desktop, the other in your Documents, to prevent Windows from renaming them, then start Firefox anew. Customize your start page(s) the way you like, then restart Firefox and check it they open the way you want.

Comment: What I want is not possible according to: [https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1115374](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1115374). Workaround with creating some tabs to open as "Homepages" in a new window is suitable workaround (but these tab are not pinned).

Comment: I also tried workaround with bookmarklet which closes current tab. But even when `window.alert()` is working from bookmark, `window.close()` does nothing.